# Unity(?) moving windows down

Tags: unity

I'm not sure exactly how to replicate this, but I normally keep all of my windows maximized (they fill the entire screen, but the window controls aren't moved to the system bar). However, sometimes a window will be moved down automatically like so:

[image]

Is there anyway to prevent this from happening? It doesn't only happen when I create a new window, but it happens for some other reason and it's been driving me nuts.

**Update:**

Turns out it happens in any window. I've tried in Firefox or Chrome, if I have a window maximized (not full screen) and I enter a full screen video (for example a FaceBook video), when leaving full screen the window moves downwards.

Here's a gif of me reproducing the issue:

[image]

**Update:**

I've switched to gnome and I love it. I also don't get this issue on gnome so it may be a Unity issue.

Comment: Yeah I have seen that happen on Chrome on a couple of occasions but I don't know how to reproduce the problem. Restarting Chrome usually fixes it.